# How to stop nginx on Mac OS X

Tags: nginx, daemon, mac-osx

I've installed and configured nginx server on my Mac from MacPorts

1. `sudo port install nginx`
2. Followed the recommendation from the port installation console and created the launchd startup item for nginx, then started the server.
3. Renamed `nginx.conf.example` to `nginx.conf` and renamed `mime.types.example` to `mime.types`.

It works fine, but I couldn't stop it.

I tried `sudo nginx -s stop`, but this doesn't stop the server, I can still see "Welcome to nginx!" page in my browser on `http://localhost/`; also I still see master and worker processes of nginx with `ps -e | grep nginx`.

What is the best way to start/stop nginx on Mac?

BTW, I've added "daemon off;" into nginx.conf - as recommended by various resources.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
# nginx -h
...
-s signal     : send signal to a master process: stop, quit, reopen, reload
...
```

Comment: When I installed nginx with MacPorts, the above command didn't work - I wasn't giving me an error, but the server kept running. But when I wiped nginx clean and reinstalled it as part of passenger nginx module installation, it works now: I can do "nginx -s stop" and it really stops the server.

Thank you!

Comment: using `nginx -s stop` worked for me but then i wasn't able to restart my server using either `nginx -s reopen`, `nginx -s reload`, `nginx -s start` or `nginx -s restart` ? How to restart? Nevermind, just executing the program `$ sudo /usr/local/sbin/nginx` restarts it.

Comment: @timpeterson `restart` or `reload` works on ... working server, if you are stoping it you just need to start it with common 'no-signal' `nginx` command.

Answer (score 16):

This command stops also stops nginx.

```
sudo nginx -s stop
```

Answer (score 8):

The correct way to do this for Nginx installed via MacPorts:

- Start: `sudo port load nginx`
- Stop: `sudo port unload nginx`

OS X uses launchd so the process of starting/stopping daemons is slightly different.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the PID of master process and do

```
kill -QUIT <master_pid>
```

Comment: How to lookup thePID?

Comment: `ps aux | grep nginx`

Comment: you may need to do `sudo kill -9 <pid>`

Answer (score 3):

You may try the following:

```
ps -lef|grep -i nginx:|awk '{ print $2}'|xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed it following the steps given by macports, I guess you added it to services started at boottime. Have you tried

```
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.nginx.plist
```

to stop the Nginx daemon?

You could also have a try with

```
sudo port unload nginx
```